# Unbrick An AT&T Sony Xperia Ion

Tags: unbricking

Yesterday I was looking for a CWM rom to flash and I found this: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2682782 . I had flashed this from my TWRP recovery that I got from here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2634375 . While I was flashing the rom, the progress bar never moved but after about a minute or so it said that flashing the rom was successful. After I tapped Reboot System the screen just went black and wouldn't turn on. I wiped dalvik-cache, cache, and data prior to doing this. My bootloader is locked and flashtool does not work because of this. Any way I can unbrick my phone? My device is a LT28at.

Edit:
After leaving it on the charger, I got a red light and after a few seconds, it turns green for the same amount of time then goes back to red. And if it matters, I have disconnected the built-in battery and plugged it in and it gave me a red blinking led.

Comment: You can't boot into recovery either?

Comment: no I have tried. I also tried force shutting it down and rebooting

Comment: And you can't access ADB from a computer either I guess?

Comment: I have tried ADB and Fastboot. My computer recognizes my device as S1 when the green light is showing but that's it.

Comment: Sorry to say, but your phone is as useful as a paperweight now then. Can you update your question with the model of the device you tried to flash so I can at least try to figure out what went wrong for you?

Comment: My device is a LT28at and AT&T is the carrier.

Comment: My best guess is that either you flashed the recovery incorrectly or the recovery itself has issues. Sorry, but as I said above,mother phone is done.

Comment: No chance of unbricking it? My computer recognizes it, so is it possible to oem unlock the bootloader with the code I got from sony?

Answer (score 0):

Calm down, your phone is not dead, you still can revive it simply by flashing a​ stock firmware using Flashtool. You should be carefully​ flashing Sony devices when having a locked bootloader.

- Download the firmware [here](http://xperiafirmware.com/8-firmware/14-sony-xperia-ion-lt28)
- Download the Flashtool [here](http://xperiafirmware.com/2-uncategorised/30-androxyde-xperia-flashtool) and install it.
- Go to the folder that contains the Flashtool (Usually C:/Flashtool) and launch it by clicking on either FlashTool.exe or FlashTool64.exe, whether on 32 bit machine or 64 bit)
- Return to the folder and open the Drivers folder, install the drivers.(C:/Flashtool/drivers).
- On Flashtool, click on the thunder icon, select Flash mode.
- Now you should open the firmware select Window. The source folder address should be `C:\User\your_name\.flashtool\firmware .` Copy the firmware you've previously downloaded to that folder. It should now appear on the selector window.
- Now click on flash button. Plug the USB cable while holding the volume down button or back button. Drivers should be installed and the flashing process started.
- Just wait until the end.
- Et voilà.

Comment: Deleted my answer.

Comment: flashing the firmware for lt28h on a lt28at harm the phone any more? And wouldn't I need an unlocked bootloader?

Comment: @JamesEstes No, you don't need an unlocked bootloader to flash a stock firmware! And I think flashing a firmware made for another variant can harm your phone unless they have same hardware specs, I think both your variant and the lt28h share same hardware specs.

Comment: ok. I was just wanting to make sure before I did this. I have also had the problem of the phone not staying in fastboot mode.

Comment: We won't use fastboot mode here. The phone will be flashed in flashmode (Connect USB cable while holding​ volume down button)

Comment: @JamesEstes how do you get in fastboot mode?

Comment: It goes into fastboot mode by itself and won't let me control when it does and doesn't @esQmo

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand